# Taglib - Ruby - Deployment - Keep getting bundle error - extconf.rb failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, taglib, engineyard

thanks for any help in advance. I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now and could definitely use some help.

I'm currently trying to deploy my app and I'm using the taglib-ruby gem and works perfectly on my local machine. But when I try to deploy via Heroku OR Engineyard, I get the following error:

```
    Installing taglib-ruby (0.5.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby19 extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for main() in -ltag... no
You must have taglib installed in order to use taglib-ruby.

Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev
Fedora/RHEL: sudo yum install taglib-devel
Brew: brew install taglib
MacPorts: sudo port install taglib

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby19
    --with-tag-dir
    --without-tag-dir
    --with-tag-include
    --without-tag-include=${tag-dir}/include
    --with-tag-lib
    --without-tag-lib=${tag-dir}/lib
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
    --with-taglib
    --without-taglib


Gem files will remain installed in /data/musicmind/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/taglib-ruby-0.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /data/musicmind/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/taglib-ruby-0.5.1/ext/taglib_base/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing taglib-ruby (0.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install taglib-ruby -v '0.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong? I'm thinking maybe there is a way to send this library with my application for deployment?

My gemfile is this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem  'rails', '3.2.8'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

gem "taglib-ruby"

gem 'json', '~> 1.6.5'

gem "multi_json", "~> 1.3.6"

#attachment management
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"

#ativity feed
gem 'public_activity', :git => "git://github.com/pokonski/public_activity.git"

gem 'jquery-rails'

#nested-album-form
gem 'nested_form', :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'

#creates pattern for widget to send form data in json back to server
gem "js_message"

gem 'kaminari'

#gem 'will_paginate'


#user authentication
gem 'devise'

#notification - basic
gem 'unread'

#id3 tag reader for songs


gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'

#admin interface
gem 'activeadmin'



#gravatar images for users with no profile picture
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'

#amazon s3 for song storage
gem 'aws-sdk'

#authentication for twitter
gem 'omniauth-twitter'

#pretty urls
gem 'friendly_id'

gem 'tire'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'nifty-generators'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'watchr'
end

#?
gem 'progress_bar'

#web intents - twitter
gem 'tweet-button'



#like buttons
gem 'facebook_share'

#rails paypal interfacing
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'

#gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'country_select'

# gem 'tiny_tds'
# gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
# gem 'ruby-odbc'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'debugger'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'minitest'
end
gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

Again, thank you, and if there is any information I can provide to help solve this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

On the Engineyard stack, you just need to add the media-libs/taglib to your package list for the gem to use.  We don't install taglib by default on the AMI.

You can do this via the dashboard ( https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21074071-Add-UNIX-Packages-to-Your-Application ), just search for taglib and select media-libs/taglib from the list.

If you want to do this on the command line for a test:

```
deploy@ip-10-66-7-217 ~ $ sudo emerge media-libs/taglib

Local copy of remote index is up-to-date and will be used.
 * Last emerge --sync was 1y 42d 54m 34s ago.
Calculating dependencies... done!

>>> Verifying ebuild manifests

>>> Emerging (1 of 1) media-libs/taglib-1.7.2
>>> Downloading 'http://distfiles.gentoo.org/distfiles/taglib-1.7.2.tar.gz'
[[ Lots of build output clipped]]
-- Installing: /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/taglib-1.7.2/image/usr/include/taglib/tag_c.h
>>> Completed installing taglib-1.7.2 into /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/taglib-1.7.2/image/

strip: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-strip --strip-unneeded -R .comment -R .GCC.command.line
   usr/lib64/libtag.so.1.7.2
   usr/lib64/libtag_c.so.0.0.0
ecompressdir: bzip2 -9 /usr/share/doc

>>> Installing (1 of 1) media-libs/taglib-1.7.2

>>> Recording media-libs/taglib in "world" favorites file...
>>> Auto-cleaning packages...

>>> No outdated packages were found on your system.

 * GNU info directory index is up-to-date.

 * IMPORTANT: 2 config files in '/etc' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
 * man page to learn how to update config files.
deploy@ip-10-66-7-217 ~ $ gem install taglib-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed taglib-ruby-0.6.0
1 gem installed
deploy@ip-10-66-7-217 ~ $
```

You can also add this via Custom Chef if you want to add this to multiple environments

```
component_version = "1.7.2"  # If your on the 2012.11 Stable-v4 stack, "1.5" if your in 2009a   

enable_package 'media-libs/taglib' do
  version component_version
end

package 'media-libs/taglib' do
  version component_version
  action :install
end
```

Finally, you can install media-libs/taglib-extras if you want support for the extra taglib-extras proprietary file formats.

Many gems with native extensions require base libraries to be installed.  Most of them can be added like this and you can open a ticket with Engine Yard support for help with more complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

for deploying `taglib` to heroku... please follow this tutorial I wrote after being stuck in this issue for a while...

http://artmees.github.io/blog/2014/06/14/heroku-taglib/

Answer (score 0):

The [taglib-heroku gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/taglib-heroku) looks like it might work.

Comment: the gem, unfortunately, is no longer working. talked to the repo holder yesterday.

Comment: It looks like the versions in the git repo seem to work.  I just added the following to a Gemfile and did a deploy. 
`gem 'cmake-heroku', :git => 'git://github.com/pjkelly/cmake-heroku.git'

gem 'taglib-heroku', :git => 'git://github.com/pjkelly/taglib-heroku.git'`

Comment: I'm getting the same error as above. Are you saying that you are getting no error when deploying to heroku? I'd like to see your log files for heroku. Maybe it'll give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like those taglib-heroku gems have been removed from pjkelly's Github account.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a custom buildpack with heroku. Use it to install taglib with no problems.

[`https://github.com/menan/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git`](https://github.com/menan/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git)

here is how you use the custom buildpack if you're unsure.

[`https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack)